# DataGrid - Duplicate row and create new binding source to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` in my `DataGrid` which contains a `TextBox`.

```
<!-- TextBox Cell -->
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="180">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">...header...</StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<!-- Duplicate Button Cell -->
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="50">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">...header...</StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Text="Duplicate" Click="DuplicateItem_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The value of the `TextBox` is bound to my `ViewModel`. Whenever I type on the `TextBox`, the source should be updated too. So the `Text` property of the `TextBox` is: `Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

I have no problem with that, but now I added a button on each row whose function is to duplicate the row itself.

```
private void DuplicateItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    TransactionItem obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as TransactionItem;
    obj.ID = transactionViewModel.TransactionDataGridItems.Count+1;
    transactionViewModel.TransactionDataGridItems.Insert(transactionViewModel.TransactionDataGridItems.IndexOf(obj)+1, obj); 
}
```

It successfully duplicates the row, but whenever I type in the `TextBox` of either of the duplicated rows, the values of both `TextBox` are changing which means it also copied the Binding source. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use the `Add` instead of `Insert` just like how I add a new item to my list.

```
private void DuplicateItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    TransactionItem obj = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as TransactionItem;
    int index = transactionViewModel.TransactionDataGridItems.IndexOf(obj) + 1;
    //do some stuff, extract the data from obj, split the concatenated string. etc.
    AddNewItem(arg....);
}
```

The only drawback here is I'm gonna need to re-evaluate the whole thing and add a new conditional in my function `AddNewItem` which overall causes 64 lines of codes.